# Not Working Mobile?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to html link with parameter by using `window.showmodaldialog`. But it does not work on a mobile phone.

How do I call this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.showModalDialog) for `showModalDialog()` lately?

> **Deprecated**
>
> *This feature has been removed from the Web.* Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Do not use it in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps using it may break at any time.

Comment: Isn't it? So which one I should use. Can you give me any advise?

Comment: @NaingLay A modern approach would be to create your own overlay that loads HTML via AJAX.

Comment: I would like to loads html via javascript. how to do ? can you advise me.

Comment: @NaingLay With AJAX, as I mentioned.

Comment: can do only with AJAX?

Comment: @NaingLay AJAX is JavaScript.